# Composite index usage

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query and I can't figure out how to take advantage of a composite index when running it. I tried an index on `type`, `for`, `buying` and `renting` properties on both nodes, but the index doesn't show up on query's `PROFILE`.

```
  MATCH (prof:Profile)
  MATCH (prop:Property)
  WHERE prof.type = prop.type
  and prof.for = prop.for
  and prof.buying = prop.buying
  and prof.renting = prop.renting
```

Is it even possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick (for the second node type) :

```
PROFILE MATCH (pp:Property)
WITH pp, pp.type as type, pp.for as for, pp.bying as buying, pp.renting as renting
MATCH (pf:Profile)
WHERE pf.type = type
AND pf.for = for
AND pf.buying = buying
AND pf.renting = renting
RETURN pp, pf;
```

The reason the index is not used is that it has no actual values to use it with, those are only available after the nodes have been scanned.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom